# "Ubuntu software" app, in Ubuntu 22.04.1. It does not open

Tags: 22.04

Good afternoon
I would like to know how to solve the problem with the "Ubuntu software" app, in Ubuntu 22.04.1.
The problem is that when I click on the application, it does not open.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This video from:
Salmorejo Geek
It has the solution, in Spanish.
Move the store to the "edge" version instead of the stable one.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niEcaw_fXjQ

I hope it works for you.

Comment: versión "edge" en lugar de estable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).